# TinyMce Magento2 2.3 Source Code Symbol / Setting

Tags: magento2, tinymce, editor

With the 2.3 version of Magento2 the TinyMce Editor lacks the possibility to edit the source code. 
how can I activate this setting with the tinymce editor

[image]